# how to add arrow of movement in the middle of each curve? python code

Tags: python, curve

i would like to add arrow of movement in each of this cruve that show the movement from beginning to the end. The position of the arrow is in the middle of the curve.
this is the code of my curve:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Definisikan sistem persamaan diferensial
[a_1, a_2] = [0.6, 0.04];
[b_1, b_2] = [0.7, 0.02];
[f_31, f_32] = [0.35, 0.3];

# Making grid
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 25)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 25)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# The model
def model(U, t):
    x, y = U
    dxdt = f_31*(1-x-y)*x - (a_1/(2-y))*(1-x-y)*x - (a_2*x*y*(1-x-y))/((2-y)*(1+y))
    dydt = f_32*(1-x-y)*y - (b_1/(2-x))*(1-x-y)*y - (b_2*x*y*(1-x-y))/((2-x)*(1+x))
    return [dxdt, dydt]

# Initial condition of population 
for i in [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]:
    z0 = [i, 0.7-i]
    plt.scatter(z0[0], z0[1], color='red', label=(i, 0.9-i))
for i in [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]:
    z0 = [i, 0.7-i]
    tspan = np.linspace(0, 1000, 2000)
    ys = odeint(model, z0, tspan)
    plt.plot(ys[:, 0], ys[:, 1], linewidth = '2')


# Plotting
plt.xlabel('$Populasi \ x_1$', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('$Populasi \ x_2$', fonts`your text`ize=18)
plt.xlim([-0.1, 1])
plt.ylim([-0.1, 1])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

python code and i want an arrow in my middle curve

Comment: Do you want a straight arrow? or, a trend like arrow?

Answer (score 0):

You can tune the position and arrow properties in the code below. My code just has some of the arrow properties-  you can find more at: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html

[image: arrows]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Definisikan sistem persamaan diferensial
[a_1, a_2] = [0.6, 0.04];
[b_1, b_2] = [0.7, 0.02];
[f_31, f_32] = [0.35, 0.3];

# Making grid
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 25)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 25)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# The model
def model(U, t):
    x, y = U
    dxdt = f_31*(1-x-y)*x - (a_1/(2-y))*(1-x-y)*x - (a_2*x*y*(1-x-y))/((2-y)*(1+y))
    dydt = f_32*(1-x-y)*y - (b_1/(2-x))*(1-x-y)*y - (b_2*x*y*(1-x-y))/((2-x)*(1+x))
    return [dxdt, dydt]

# Initial condition of population 
for i in [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]:
    z0 = [i, 0.7-i]
    plt.scatter(z0[0], z0[1], color='red', label=(i, 0.9-i))
for i in [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]:
    z0 = [i, 0.7-i]
    tspan = np.linspace(0, 1000, 2000)
    ys = odeint(model, z0, tspan)
    #Store line in order to retrieve its colour
    line = plt.plot(ys[:, 0], ys[:, 1], linewidth = '2')
    
    #Plot coloured arrow
    plt.arrow(
        x=ys[15, 0],
        y=ys[15, 1],
        dx=ys[16, 0] - ys[15, 0],
        dy=ys[16, 1] - ys[15, 1],
        width=0.006,
        length_includes_head=True,
        overhang=0.2,
        edgecolor='none',
        color=line[0].get_color(),
        zorder=2
    )

# Plotting
plt.xlabel('$Populasi \ x_1$', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('$Populasi \ x_2$', fontsize=18)
plt.xlim([-0.1, 1])
plt.ylim([-0.1, 1])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```